# Control that can close installator

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

Im trying to make `Control` with `Dialog` that cloes all instalator when i hit `PushButton`:

```
<Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="100" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Exit">
          <Publish Event="Finish" Value="Return">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

When i press it, my installator returns code `2812`.

How to write `Control` on `Dialog`, that will close Installator without any error?

Code:

```
...
<UI >
      <Dialog Id="InstallDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Setup" NoMinimize="yes">
        <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
          <Text>Ready to Install</Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Install" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Install">
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" />
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="100" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Exit">
          <Publish Event="Finish" Value="Return">1</Publish>
        </Control>
      </Dialog>
    </UI>

...

<Upgrade Id="!(loc.UpgradeCode)">
      <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect='yes' Property='NEWERFOUND'
        Minimum='1.0.1' IncludeMinimum='no' />
    </Upgrade>

...

<InstallUISequence>
      <Show Dialog="InstallDlg" After='FindRelatedProducts' >NEWERFOUND</Show>
    </InstallUISequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want a confirmation dialog to avoid an accidental exit. Change your code for that button to:

```
<Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="100" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="Exit">
      <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Exit">1</Publish>
</Control>
```